# Laravel insert record in 2 tables from single model

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using Lumen(Laravel), structure of 2 tables is given below

```
Language:
id,
lanugae_name,

Language_country
id,
language_id,
country_id,
```

I have created a model for lanugage table. But i want when i am inserting record in Language table on same time how i can insert its relationship with country in language_country ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) method

In your case:

```
$language->countries()->attach($countryId);
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have defined the relationship between Language and Country on the language model, you can use the `attach()` method to do this.

```
$language->countries()->attach($country->id);
```

Information about defining the relationship and more on the attach() method is at: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships